# Android Databinding, set xml style from a function call

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, data-binding

#### App description

I'm using data binding in a simple android app which shows a list of books.

I use a `RecyclerView` to list them.
I prepared a `Book` object which has a title and a color.

```
data class Book(val title: String, val color: BookColor)
```

Where `BookColor` is an enum, containing 10 different colors.

Now, I created 10 different styles (tailored for the `BookView` custom view) for all the 10 colors (so that they are compatible with dark mode).

#### Issue

What I can't figure out is how to get the book style applied to the actual `BookView` using databinding.

I would like to use (from databinding) a function I can define in a helper class, something like:

```
fun mapColorToStyle(color: Book)
```

accepting a `Book` object, which will map `book.color` to its matching XML style.

Then the style will be returned to the view (the `RecyclerView` item).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>
    <variable
        name="book"
        type="com.x.y.model.Book" />
</data>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <BookView
        android:id="@+id/squircle"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="26dp"
        style="@{???}"
    />

    <TextView ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

Is there a way to achieve this without setting the style programmatically (which I doubt is a nice solution)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the binding adapter instead of applying the style mentioned above.

```
@BindingAdapter("bindBookViewStyle")
fun TextView.bindViewStyle(bookColor: BookColor) {
    val style =  mapColorToStyle(bookColor)
    TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(this, style)
}
```

and then modify your item xml

```
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>

    <variable
        name="book"
        type="com.xx.xx.Book" />
</data>

<BookView app:bindBookViewStyle="@{book.color}" />
```

[Please check similar answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31980342/android-data-binding-style)

Comment: I'll try, but BookView is not a TextView

Comment: @Andrea yes, that is not a problem, the sample is just for your reference. You can invoke the appropriate call inside the Binding adapter.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the insight. You also happen to know what's the appropriate style-setting call if BookView is AppCompatImageView?