# How to set style resource from data binding using **style** attribute

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

In viewModel i had a function like this:

```
fun getTextInputStyle(): Int {
val style = if (isTrue) {
    R.style.styleOne
} else {
    R.style.styleTwo
}
return style
```

}

In XML file there is a textInputLayout call the function from ViewModel:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/til_first_name"
style="@{viewModel.getTextInputStyle}"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_16sdp"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_13sdp"
android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_16sdp"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rg_title">


</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

And here the error logged in the console:

```
      Cannot find a setter for 
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout style> 
        that 
        accepts parameter type 'int'
   If a binding adapter provides the setter, check that the adapter is 
   annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches.
```

Comment: Maybe this works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692527/android-databinding-set-xml-style-from-a-function-call; you can simplify your function like this: `fun getTextInputStyle() = if(isTrue) R.style.styleOne else R.style.styleTwo`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but that wont work for my case i want to change the whole style not the  setTextAppearance as mentioned in the question you provide.

Answer (score 1):

You can use binding adapter to set style like this.

```
@BindingAdapter("bindTextViewStyle")
fun TextView.bindTextViewStyle(styleResourceId: Int) {
    this.style(styleResourceId)
}
```

and in XML

```
<TextView
    app:bindTextViewStyle="@{viewModel.textStyle}"
    .../>
```

Refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/64009888/20839582

Comment: Where did you get **this.style **from? there is no such a thing for TextView or any view in android

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64009888/20839582.

Comment: Edited answer and when using binding adapter, you can access properties of view using "this".